"I have no idea what you were talking about" or "I have no idea what you talked about"?
To reply to another person's words, which one is correct "I have no idea what you were talking about" or "I have no idea what you talked about"?
i.e. Should I use past continuous tense or just simple past tense?
To make my question more clear, I see people use past continuous tense but I don't understand that because the one I reply these words to has already said something, so why use past continuous tense?

The former sentence is the more common usage. The second one would describe what you talked about at an earlier time; yesterday or last night.

Are you trying to say that you heard them talk but you did not understand the meaning?  Or that you did not even hear them talk?

Hi I have updated my question to make it more clearer why I have this question in the first place. @JohnGordon the former.

The first sentence in your pair means the speaker does not know at all what the other person meant. In phrasing it thus, the speaker essentially asserts that the other person was incomprehensible, or at least that the other person did not explain themselves adequately.
The second sentence means merely that the speaker is not in the least aware of what topic the other person spoke on. That’s different. It might fit a context in which the speaker knows that the other person had been talking (at some time in the past) but has not been informed of the subject of the other person’s remarks.
As an example of the difference, if I told you, “I gave a speech yesterday. I wonder if my topic was well chosen,” you might reply, “I can’t be of any help to you on that. Not having been there myself, I have no idea what you talked about.” Maybe it was a history lecture or a political oration, or maybe it was a presentation about a recent medical breakthrough or a discussion of garden design; in this scenario you don’t know which it was, and that’s all you’re saying. You’re not commenting about the clarity of my presentation. Only someone who had been present for my speech and understood nearly none of it could say, “I have no idea what you were talking about.”

No; it's also possible to use "I have no idea what you were talking about" with reference to the subject matter. "I have no idea what you were talking about, but I overheard  someone coming out of the lecture theatre saying he was going to complain to the dean about some of your assertions."

Ok, @EdwinAshworth, I’ll buy that.

But, @EdwinAshworth, only if the issue involves some particular period during which (or instant at which) the addressee was indeed taking.

The first sentence "I have no idea what you were talking about.", is likely more common, but has three issues:

Depending on the context, it can come across as a little bit hostile or mildly confrontational.
It is ambiguous. It doesn't identify if the issue was the lack of the speaker's chosen words, or the responder simply was not present to hear what was said.
Depending on the context, it can come across as trying to deny something occurred, as if you are formulating a legal or argument defense.

Although less common, the second sentence, "I have no idea what you talked about." is typically the better choice of the two choices provided.  It's a simple fact-based statement indicating you are unaware what that other person talked about.  It doesn't come across as confrontational or defensive.  Two improved choices are:

"I am unaware of what you talked about."  This makes it clear that the responder is literally unaware of what the speaker said.  This can be followed up with a statement such as "I was not present."
"I did not completely understand what you talked about."  This makes it clear that the responder heard what the speaker said, but did not fully understand it.


Thanks I didn't know what you said at all. When I asked my question I was actually curious about why I can use past continuous tense here because I see people use that.

I have updated my question to make it more clearer why I have this question in the first place.
